# gremlin find all connected vertices

Tags: graph, gremlin

I have a graph where a -> b, b -> c, c -> d and so on. Each vertex has a createdOn property. I would like to start with a and get all vertices whose createdOn property is less than a particular date, say 5/31/2017. I've tried using repeat and until but am not getting the results I would expect. `g.V('a').repeat(outE().inV()).until(has('changedOn',gt('5/31/2017 12:00:00 AM')))` I'm new to this so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin it is always best to supply a sample graph as a Gremlin script that can be pasted into the Gremlin Console, like this:

```
g.addV('person').property('name','a').property('changedOn', '2018-01-15T11:53:00').as('a').
  addV('person').property('name','b').property('changedOn', '2018-01-15T12:53:00').as('b').
  addV('person').property('name','c').property('changedOn', '2018-01-15T13:53:00').as('c').
  addV('person').property('name','d').property('changedOn', '2018-01-15T14:53:00').as('d').
  addV('person').property('name','e').property('changedOn', '2018-01-15T13:53:00').as('e').
  addE('link').from('a').to('b').
  addE('link').from('b').to('c').
  addE('link').from('c').to('d').
  addE('link').from('d').to('e').iterate()
```

Given that graph, you can solve your problem with `emit()` which explains to `repeat()` the traversers that should continue out of that step:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','a').
......1>   emit(has('changedOn',lt('2018-01-15T14:53:00'))).
......2>   repeat(out('link')).
......3>   valueMap()
==>[name:[a],changedOn:[2018-01-15T11:53:00]]
==>[name:[b],changedOn:[2018-01-15T12:53:00]]
==>[name:[c],changedOn:[2018-01-15T13:53:00]]
==>[name:[e],changedOn:[2018-01-15T13:53:00]]
```

Several things to note:

1. The positioning of the `emit()` happens prior to `repeat()` in this case because you want to emit the "a" vertex - if it is positioned after `repeat()` you wont' get that vertex.
2. You tried to use `until()` but that just controls the when the loop stops. In my example, it runs until there are no more vertices in the chain - you might yet need a `until()` step depending on your situation.
3. I don't know what form of date you are storing in your graph, but I used ISO-8601 format - you would probably want to do the same or just store the date as a long. Either is comparable for "less than" and "greater than" purposes and would be portable to all graph databases I'm aware of.